# .net3.5 applications with .net framework 4

Tags: .net, windows, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, compatibility

Can I run applications compiled with .net framework 3.5 on a computer with .net framework 4 installed (.net framework 3.5 is not installed)?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. The CLR 4.0 is backwards compatible with assemblies compiled against .NET 3.5.

Comment: Does that imply the the same for 3.0?

Comment: Yes, same for .NET 2.0. Not sure about .NET 1.0 and 1.1 though but who cares about them anyways :-)

Comment: But when I'm trying to do so, it crash (It says that it can't load the assembly ...servicemodel.... version 3.0)...

Comment: Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: When you migrate the project in Visual Studio 2010 it should automatically change the reference of the BCL assemblies to 4.0. It seems this is not the case. You might need to change the references.

Comment: Oops... Enter sends the question... If the application was compiled with vs 2008 (and hence using .net 3.5), can I run it on .net 4 computer?

Comment: Darin, you're comment seems to disagree with your answer. The question states that the project is not migrated in VS2010 or recompiled. So I believe the question still stands. Can such a project/solution work, unaltered? Mattan's comment suggests it cannot.